# Ext.NET SWFUpload

Tags: c#, ext.net

I am trying to run Ext.NET example:
http://examples.ext.net/#/MultiUpload/Basic/Grid/

But get following error message:

> Something went wrong while loading SWFUpload. If this were a real
>   application we'd clean up and then give you an alternative.

I have also tried to create sample application but still get the same error.

Can someone who has already worked with Ext.NET/SWFUpload help how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is likely caused by Flash being disabled in the browser. The SWFUpload component requires Flash.

Hope this helps.